# How to make Visual Studio '17 do a build before launching in debug mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a console app that I inherited form the developer who I replaced. When I make code changes and then run it in debug mode, the changes do not take effect unless I remember to build the solution first.

I've never seen this before.  Usually when you enter debug mode, it does a build.  I've looked through the properties of both the solution and the project, but I'm not seeing where to set this.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeev's answer lead me to the solution.

```
Options -> Projects and Solution -> Build and Run
```

Un-check the checkbox that says `Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run`.

Answer (score 1):

> Right-click the Solution (not project) in the Solution Explorer and
>   select Configuration Manager. Check if Build is turn off for the
>   current configuration.

If it is checked un check it and check it back again that should do the trick

Comment: yeah, I had checked that already.  I should have said that specifically in the OP. I did do as you suggested and unchecked then checked  the boxes again, but I still get the same result.  This isn't a huge deal - just a minor annoyance.

Comment: I understand i had similar issue and that worked for me hopefully someone else will have a solution for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try going to `Options -> Projects and Solution -> Build and Run` and making sure that `On Run, when projects are out of date` is not set to `Never build`

Comment: Not the answer, but it lead me to the answer!  It was set to "Prompt to build".  I changed it to "Always build" but that didn't do the trick. Then, I noticed that this checkbox was checked: "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run".  I unchecked that checkbox, and that did the trick.